# Python matplotlib add text below plot only if condition matches

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, if-statement

I am using Matplotlib and PysimpleGUI (for the front end) and am creating a graph. I have a list as the output from earlier processing, however I want to add certain text only if this item is found in the list, else it can be some default text. Example below:

```
my_list=['hello', 'mouse', 'lion']

def my_graph(values, value1,  title):
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
    plt.figure(figsize=(6,3))
    plt.bar(values)
    plt.plot(values1)
    plt.xlabel("My values",fontsize =6)
    plt.title(title)
    plt.legend(loc="upper right")
    fig = plt.gcf()
    return fig

output = my_graph(values, value1, value2, title)
if 'lion' in my_list:
     ####add some text below the plot
else:
    ###some other text
```

Can anyone help me out please and let me know what I might be doing wrong? I'm not sure how possible it is doing this outside the function either.

Thanks

Comment: try not to do import inside the function. Also your code has a few syntax errors (my_list should be of strings and Values should be values)

Comment: will update it now!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes you can do that. Here is an illustration:

```
if 'lion' in my_list:
     output.text(0.5,-0.1,'some text', ha='center')
else:
     output.text(0.5,-0.1,'some other text', ha='center')
```

see [matplotlib.pyplot.text](https://matplotlib.org/3.3.3/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.text.html)